# Emulating the Reminders App "Add" Footer in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, interface-builder

I could use some pointers in trying to create a "Add" footer similar to the Reminders app on iPhone, whether by Interface Builder and/or code.

More specially, I have a list of data and want to have an editable "Add" row always available like this:

- When the bottom of the list is visible, you see "Add" at the bottom
- When not visible, the "Add" row floats and remains visible/accessible at bottom of the view
- When the keyboard is shown, "Add" row sits right above the keyboard

So far, I've tried using a table view controller and putting an EditFieldView in the table footer.  That takes care of one feature.  But I'm not sure where to go from there without writing code. I'm still kind of new to iOS UI and am hoping to avoid re-inventing functionality that already exists.

Comment: Reminders is using a Keyboard Accessory to show the "add" button above the keyboard. It most likely listens for Keyboard notifications and hides and shows the table footer. You can also have your table adjust its frame with the keyboard so if it is actually a footer then your footer will move up too. Nothing special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for making your view sit above the keyboard but still at the bottom of the table when the keyboard is not visible.

I added a red UIView. When you tap on it, the keyboard will show and you can see it animate into position above the keyboard. When you tap on the cell itself, you can see the keyboard dismiss and the view moves back to the bottom of the table.

There are other ways to do this such as using a Keyboard Accessory view and a view attached to the bottom. However, I won't get into that.

Example using keyboard notifications:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  SO
//
//  Created by Brandon T on 2017-02-03.
//  Copyright © 2017 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var table: UITableView!
    var tableFooter: UIView!
    var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var dummyTextField: UITextField?

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Notifications
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

        //Setup Views
        self.table = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame, style: .grouped)
        self.table.delegate = self
        self.table.dataSource = self


        self.tableFooter = UIView()
        self.tableFooter.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onViewTap(recognizer:)))
        recognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        recognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        self.tableFooter.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)


        //Constraints
        self.view.addSubview(self.table)
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableFooter)

        self.table.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.table.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.table.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true

        self.tableFooter.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.tableFooter.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        self.tableFooter.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.table.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.tableFooter.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0).isActive = true
        self.bottomConstraint = self.tableFooter.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
        self.bottomConstraint.isActive = true


        self.table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.tableFooter.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
            let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
            let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
            let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: TimeInterval(0), options: animationCurve, animations: {
                if (self.bottomConstraint.constant <= 0.0) {
                    self.bottomConstraint.constant = -endFrame!.size.height
                }
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { (finished) in

            })
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
            let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
            let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
            let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: TimeInterval(0), options: animationCurve, animations: {
                self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0.0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { (finished) in

            })
        }
    }


    //TableView
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.00001
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0.00001
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID")

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cellID")
            cell!.selectionStyle = .none

            self.dummyTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 25.0, width: 100, height: 50))
            cell!.contentView.addSubview(self.dummyTextField!)
        }

        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell!.textLabel?.text = "Test - \(indexPath.row)"



        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.dummyTextField!.resignFirstResponder()
        self.dummyTextField!.endEditing(true)

        self.view.resignFirstResponder()
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func onViewTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        self.dummyTextField?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction. I'm researching Accessory Views more thoroughly.